# Alternative for replit

Tags: pythoninterpreter

I and my friend were working with a python project on replit
We were working with some modules when we got an error saying that we had reached the maximum number of libraries stored in the server.
Is there any good alternative to replit?

the features i am looking for the website alternative of replit:

(1) python interpreter

(2) team projects

(3) free

(4) live multi-person editing (meaning that if a person edits a piece of code it should appear without refreshing)

(5) pre-installed common modules

(6) auto-complete variables, brackets

(7) atleast 250mb project space

if there is a website which meets all these requirement then please give the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try https://codebunk.com/. You can also use collaboration plugins for native ides. Atom has teletype. Vscode has liveshare. Jetbrains has codewithme.

Comment: To be 100% clear, CodeWithMe from JetBrains is a pair programming or swarm programming plugin for the intellij IDE. It is therefore not comparable to a hosted platform such as Replit and Codebunk looks Alpha as I write...just compared it to Replit.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/ or https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/codesandbox-nuxt/tree/master/ would be viable alternatives from what i have seen recommended on Nuxt.